# Nagios config file syntax

Tags: nagios, nagiosxi

I need to know the name of Nagios config files syntax, and how to parsing.

An example of Nagios host define.

```
define host {
    host_name                       bogus-router
    alias                           Bogus Router #1
    address                         192.168.1.254
    parents                         server-backbone
    check_command                   check-host-alive
    check_interval                  5
    retry_interval                  1
    max_check_attempts              5
    check_period                    24x7
    process_perf_data               0
    retain_nonstatus_information    0
    contact_groups                  router-admins
    notification_interval           30
    notification_period             24x7
    notification_options            d,u,r
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome here at StackOverflow. I am not sure what is your problem, but try check out official documentation - https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html#host

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an example of **the** Nagios configuration file. **The** Nagios configuration file (nagios.cfg) has an INI file syntax, i.e. `name=value` (but no sections).

The example you give is a Nagios **object configuration** file (referred to via `cfg_file` in the above config file), but I'm not sure what you're asking. The "name" of the syntax? I'm pretty sure it's not a standard syntax but simply "the" Nagios object syntax. In its simplest form, it's

```
define [object type] {
    attribute value
}
```

New lines separate attributes. The attribute never contains spaces, but the value may, depending on the attribute. Some attributes also take multiple values (like `notification_options`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think as you mentioned its just Nagios object syntax.
I just going to write a script to parse Nagios objects and doing some daily tasks on Nagios, that's why I asked about the syntax.